# ngx-timepicker-field problem with HH input in 24 hours format

Tags: angular, timepicker

I am not able to set the double digit times format in [format] = "24".
The problem is only with the morning hours ... I need 4 digits to appear, such as 09:30. Returns me 9:30

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSs4b.jpg

my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOdgU.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Seems that the four digit format depends on the Internationalization settings.

Had to add: .setLocale('es-419') to my NgxMaterialTimepickerModule